# Having four sites to jump between is ridiculous

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

We need a trilogy site where each of the four sites in the trilogy is in a tab.

Comment: What's a trilogy tab?

Comment: When I go to Google News, I see all the news. But I can go to "sports" or "business" or "weather" if I like and see only those stories. That's like what I want from the trilogy. I could see all the recent things going on, or I could filter down to one category.

Comment: I sympathize with the viewpoint...it has gotten complex to work out which question goes where, and it is a (mild) nuisance having to switch between the various sites.  One option would be links to the sister sites on each page - top, bottom or at the side (under or near the ads and stats)

Comment: They are linked at the bottom, which is silly. It means hitting the "End" key to find the link and switch.

Comment: Open each site in a browser tag?

Comment: One site to rule them all... and in the darkness bind them?

Comment: Try 26 sites, then ;-P. (Of course, we have got stackexchange.com itself, now, which helps.)

Answer (score 8):

Why not make your own mashup site? You might just make some money off of it!

Another option is consolidating most of your interests to RSS feeds on something like Google Reader. That is what I do.

Comment: That's a good idea.

Comment: [Already done it](http://173.203.84.26/joshuakehn/codebase/homestead/). :)

Answer (score 6):

Answered on the blog:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/why-cant-you-have-just-one-site/

Comment: When the bad guys are wrecking havoc in your town, do you call the Justice League or do you call an individual superhero, and he refers you to another one because it's a border-case of whether he's the right hero to handle it?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com) could help with this. You can input multiple feeds, filter and re-read it afterwards. I'm at least going to try that.

I still think that the most annoying thing of following all three web-sites is checking up on your answers. Just the feature of your profile on one site would list your responses and status on all the other linked accounts would work wonders for me.

I mean, the accounts are already linked, why not provide a common notification platform for all sites?

Answer (score 3):

This is the sort of thing I'd hoped would get accomplished by a desktop app, but we're still lacking an API for that.

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked numerous times and there has already been a couple posts already about using a Greasemonkey script to allow you to add in some of the information at the top of the site where your current rep information is.

Comment: But that's not a solution, that's a workaround.

Comment: Thor K.H most people don't believe there needs to be a work-around. I am on the fence on the issue. Sure it would be nice to be able to have a central location to have all my SO-family related information in one space, but I also am quite adept at using bookmarks (and Greasemonkey) so that it doesn't bother me.

Answer (score 2):

If only he added another site that could combine all of them in aggregate...what I really would like is just a way to not have more hurdles in order to log in (I already have an openid login, I'm on Serverfault, but someone decided my question belonged on SuperUser, so then I had to track down the password to get into the beta site, then find the question after logging into that one...

I think it would be nice to navigate the sites more *transparently* so that there is less resistance and less hassle. There are questions that are *related* enough that they border between topics found on SU and SF, for example. As a sysadmin I have to deal with user issues. Sometimes those issues could be found by home users or sysadmins in labs and workplaces, so then you're going to have duplicates and it's harder to move from site to site to find what you want...

It seems as if the whole team has this picture in their head of some kind of self-organizing emergent wiki, which would be great, but just so long as the users aren't getting agitated because they have to triple log in to find an answer (as I just got directed from SF to SU but had to go to meta then back to SU and go through logging in and associating my profile to do...AGH!)

The team will do what they want in the end and that's fine and dandy. I love the sites. I'm just wishing there was an easy way to have them accept my login as a portal and easily slide among the sites and content with a filtering system of some sort, like "make serverfault my primary portal" as the default and the others with their own themes show visually where I am and I can aggregate information without keeping track of what I'm logged into and have to log out of each time.

Comment: Yeah, right now meta and stackoverflow and superuser are remembering me, but somehow I got logged off from serverfault (went too long between visits?) and I haven't bothered to log in for a week to see if I have any more responses over there. Logging in is just enough of a hassle that if I don't know if anything's waiting for me there I won't do it.

Comment: Or like forgetting that I put this up a week ago and just thought of logging in here to find if anything's changed?

It would be nice to aggregate replies in one place, like making the user profile-centric and not site-centric! I don't mind various statistics kept separately in rep and whatnot, but jumping site to site drives me batty.

Answer (score 1):

Use [iGoogle](http://www.google.com/ig). Create a tab for each site. Within each tab:

- subscribe to the Newest questions feed
- subscribe Most Popular
- subscribe to your favorite tags. (i.e. python, c++, ms-access, whathaveyou.)

Answer (score 0):

They don't need a trilogy site to combine the other four sites; they just need **one site, period** (which they have, called Stack Overflow), and have people tag things appropriately. Separating things into different domains, creating duplicate user accounts with different reputation levels and potentially different logins, and fragmenting the community needlessly was a bad idea. Don't focus on making workarounds to the real problem; they should just consolidate it all back into SO.

Comment: Completely disagree.

Comment: Completely disagree with your disagreement.