# user card pop-up: an option to show combined flair instead of local

Tags: feature-request, flair, user-card, combined-flair

Currently (SO *rev 2011.9.19.7*), user card popup shows "local" flair (shown as left at the picture below).

I think it would be nice to have an option for it to show combined flair instead (shown to the right at the image below).

[image: picture with requested flair options]

Comment: Not enough freehand.

Comment: I agree; the reputation and the badges for the SE site are already shown to the right of the popup. It makes sense to show the global reputation, and badges, in the popup.

Comment: @agf updated with f/h powered picture

Comment: Much better. +0! (Since you already got my +1)