# Topics that don't belong anywhere OR could belong everywhere

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, superuser, serverfault, sharing

I asked a question (which turns out to be pretty useless) but its the sort of thing that applies to both server fault and stack overflow. 
I have been told it should be on superuser now.

[What are the best / recommended video cards for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220288/what-are-the-best-recommended-video-cards-for-wpf-closed) (Stack Overflow)

[What are the best / recommended video cards for WPF](https://serverfault.com/questions/49154/what-are-the-best-recommended-video-cards-for-wpf) (Server Fault)

The real issue is, given who you are (I was coming from a developer mindset trying to advise a company what to tell their customers technical staff) you would think to put it on different sites, and depending on who you are you would look for the answer on different sites.

Basically as i see it its the little wedge in the middle of the venn diagarm. 
What are the guidelines for this sort of thing? Should there be a "share between all sites style"? is there one and I simply haven't found it yet?

Comment: Ok to extend this a bit further.
The catalyst for me asking was to fill in a "system requirements" sheet to go out with a product, this I can see being a super user style question perhaps (if I could login). 
The programmer in me is interested in the underlying technology and its implemntation. The more you know about a technology the more you can fit it into the mental picture.

Comment: Personally, I find Bash and Batch straddle the line between all three sites. If your using it to control a server, SF seems best. If your writing complicated ones, SO seems best. And Bash is something a Linux power user would frequently use, so it could also go on SU.

Comment: Go to http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/ for the password to Super User.

Answer (score 2):

So far there is no set guideline, it depends on 5 users opinion, i.e. 5 users flagging the post to be moved. Or one single moderator.

I second your findings that there are questions that could be hosted in all three sites, depending on the viewpoint of the questioner. I said so [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/why-do-we-need-the-trilogy-instead-of-just-one-site/4696#4696).

As I expressed in that answer, I do not think that shared questions (or even a single shared site) would help any.The answers might differ totally - especially after beta is over in superuser and there will be more users on the site as opposed to the SO/SF crowd on there now mainly.

Maybe it helps to write down the business case in the question to locate the site best fit.

Comment: Adding the business case and the motivation for the question will help focus it.

Answer (score 0):

Questions that can belong anywhere probably could do with some editing to focus them on the correct site.

How you ask influences how the people answering will attack the question, if at all.

Your question reads like it could fit into Super User, that place being about computers, with you asking about video cards.

And then there are questions like [What is the popularity of various desktop resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258978/poll-what-is-the-popularity-of-various-desktop-resolutions) that just don't work, [even if copy-and-pasted to ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/52592/poll-what-is-the-popularity-of-various-desktop-resolutions).

Comment: Word is very important, but there is a small (possibly _very_ small subset of questions which have equal footing on multiple sites.

Comment: If you don't already know the answer to your question, you can't know where you will get the best answer.  Maybe it will come from a different point of view than you were expecting, if you were going about something in a sub-optimal way in the first place.  Making questions more narrow is good for organizing the various sites, but perhaps not always good for the users themselves.