# Re-ask a question on superuser if not getting any answers on serverfault

Tags: support

Would a question on superuser get flagged/closed if it was already asked on serverfault. I think the question could be asked on either?

Comment: As a side note to this, if you look at the question count and the user count, you can see that stackoverflow has about 10x the traffic as serverfault and superuser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had this happen to me. Asked a question on SU and a couple days passed without any real input and then a few minutes after posting on SF I had my answer. In this case I think there's value in leaving it on both sites, with the answer on both, because the question was about a small business level firewall which people may be using in their home, like me, or in their small business. I think being flagged/closed will depend on the situation more than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not getting you question answered successfully on ServerFault, you really need to ask yourself if it belongs on SuperUser first of all.

If you figure it can make it on SuperUser without getting punted back to another site, the simplest thing to do would be to flag your own question for moderator attention and kindly ask that it gets migrated over. This would allow it to move over and keep all the answers that may have been posted already.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't. However you can ask your SF question to be moved to SU. Be careful because the question might be sent back to SF otherwise.

Comment: Its that remote manage IIS 7.5 question, I thought someone on superuser, who doesn't frequent serverfault might have an answer.

Comment: I vote for the transfer, why create a duplicate if one version proves to be ineffective?

Comment: I don't think that particular question will get any better answers on SU. That however is just my opinion. Remember SU only came out of Beta on Tuesday, and most of the regulars are on all the sites already. –

Comment: @Diago, I was thinking that anyone who would know an answer would probably frequent both sites also, it was more about possibly getting more exposure since the question has only been viewed 25 times.

Answer (score 0):

There might be questions that value being on multiple platforms, as I explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/topics-that-dont-belong-anywhere-or-could-belong-everywhere/11869#11869) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/why-do-we-need-the-trilogy-instead-of-just-one-site/4696#4696). Do you think, that keeping the question on SF, maybe with a bounty, will produce valuable answers? Different from the ones on SU? I think it really depends on the expected answers and chances to get them whether you ask the question on multiple sites. But it is a valid possibility, as the audience differs (especially now that SU is public and not only known to SO/SF community).

So I hope that such questions will not be closed!

Comment: Don't really have enough rep (73) to offer a bounty that would entice anyone to look at it