# Will the new sites on stackexchange work?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we need the trilogy instead of just one site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/why-do-we-need-the-trilogy-instead-of-just-one-site)

I understand stackoverflow is a hugely popular site but this whole new stackexchange concept many not work.

My proposal is to let users create all kinds of questions on one site and use whatever tagging appropriate for them. It is kinda getting crazy to log on to different sites. My guess is that this experiment will fail.

I am curious to hear what others have to say.

Comment: [One site to rule them all.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/why-do-we-need-the-trilogy-instead-of-just-one-site)

Comment: Yeah, a site where everybody can ask questions about *everything* - computer programming, gardening, handguns, you name it - and everybody tags them to sort topically. *That* sounds like a recipe for success....

Answer (score 1):

1) Why do you say it won't work? Can you elaborate on that?

2) Your proposal is [already implemented](http://answers.yahoo.com/)!

Comment: I know answers.yahoo is already implemented and I think we should strive to make/scale stackoverflow similar to answers.yahoo.com rather than having multiple logins/sites and then worry about rules on closing down the questions as they do not belong to the site.

I personally feel that after about 6-8 weeks, Joel will realize that it ain't working as all the professional photographers will only go to specific sites or forums on strobist or cooking forums on chowhound.com..

Comment: What is your take?