# Where to discuss/question the various Stack Exchange decisions/stances?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I thought meta was this type of place, but from what I gather, is not.

Basically, I want to discuss with others whether or not it's sub-optimal having many related, but different sub-programming topic oriented sites like Code Exchange, Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, ...

Sometimes you need an Exchange dedicated to simply asking routing questions for your question like "is an nginx question ok to ask in SO or is a SF quests" which in my experience is a 'well, that depends...' situation.

Which of the various Stack Exchange sites is best suited for discussing/complaining/ranting on topics like this?

Comment: This is the place, but I suggest that you try and read older posts about the subject here before posting a new one. Some topics have been discussed at length here already, and the community reacts pretty harshly sometimes when a user posts about them again without doing their homework first.

Comment: @MadScientist good advice, and yep there's an ancient one I dug up to add my vote to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/why-do-we-need-the-trilogy-instead-of-just-one-site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Which of the various Stack Exchange sites is best suited for
>   discussing/complaining/ranting on topics like this?

Meta (here) is exactly the right place.

Tag the question as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), say what you think, justify it from your side and people who agree/disagree will comment or answer.

But *ranting*? ***No***. Just no.

---

However *per-site* metas aren't the place to ask this sort of question. The difference is that Meta (here) is the meta for the entirety of the Stack Exchange sites, so you can talk about bugs/features/discussions/etc... that relate to every SE site, but per-site meta's are specifically for that site.

Comment: Cool, so by per-site meta, you mean StackExhange Meta is the one ring to rule them all, so any cross sub-site meta question should go here.

Comment: @Ray exactly right :)

Comment: @David what did the blank comment at the beginning do??

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Allowed me to fix the one character typo in the tag name ;) (min 6 characters required as I don't yet have edit privileges on meta.se)

Comment: @DavidPostill ahh - that explains it! No problem and thanks for the typo correction :)