# Full-caps posts should be flagged or banned

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, scripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [BLOCK QUESTIONS IN ALL CAPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121301/block-questions-in-all-caps)

Based on [this chat conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/fullcaps):

I suggest Community ♦ should flag full-caps questions and answers. Perhaps full-caps questions should be blocked from even being posted at all, as too-short posts are.

(Full-caps *answers* should perhaps not be blocked from being posted. On programming sites and English SE, an answer might perhaps be a bit of code or a quotation in full-caps. OTOH, as noted in the comments to this question, even answers like those are probably better off with some prose added.)

Comment: Compare http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9912 (not a duplicate).

Comment: -1 I THINK THIS IS A DUMB IDEA.  EVERYBODY KNOWS CAPS=COOL.

Comment: WHAT IF IT'S AN OLD SCHOOL FORTRAN PROGRAM? ;)

Comment: @jonsca, I actually thought before posting of the various *.se sites and whether some might have some fullcaps posts (some of the programming-related ones or English.se), but then realized that even if they're _discussing_ fullcaps material, at least some of the _question_ should not be fullcaps. **However** the same is not true for **answers**, which can be just code (or, on English.se, a quote), so perhaps a flag is better than not allowing the post through. The flag can always be cleared by a mod, of course. or perhaps don't let questions through, and flag answers.

Comment: @msh210 Yes, I'm sure they would be the exception, not the rule.  That was more of a tongue-in-cheek statement.

Comment: ... Actually, I'll edit my question now to reflect this.

Comment: @msh210 I'd make the restriction apply to answers as well. It's unlikely that a high-quality answer would consist of just code. If the answer needs to contain Fortran, and this filter forces the answerer to add some prose explanation of the code, I say so much the better.

Comment: I'll back "flag questions where body == body.toupper"

Comment: @jcolebrand, [japanese.se] might have a problem with that. (Actually, I don't see any posts on there all in Japanese at a glance, but I'd not be surprised if there are some. [german.se] definitely has [some](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1532) in German.)

Comment: @Won't: WHY YOU NO -1???

Comment: @msh210: Instead of saying "see the comments", it would be better if you paraphrased jonsca's comment and included it in your question. What if he decided to delete his comment later on?

Comment: @yoda, it's not jonsca's to see, but mine and Isaac Moses's. Fair enough, though: I'll paraphrase rather than refer.

Comment: @Isaac: It's not just all caps :) "Consistently separating words by spaces became a general custom about the tenth century A.D., and lasted until about 1957, when FORTRAN abandoned the practice." -Sun FORTRAN Reference Manual

Comment: Maybe there should be a check for what percentage of the post is all caps, and flag above that value. While all-caps code might be valid, one presumes that there would be some normal-cased explanatory text to go with it.

Comment: The same feature might be useful for all-lowercase posts, too.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that when a user tries to post a question or answer in all caps, they will not only be blocked from posting it but also be subjected to a maximum-volume clip of one of Samuel L. Jackson's famous movie rants, be they about [snakes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLaX8UvVUQw), [Marsellus Wallace](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCrDuGyZ6FA), or [who deserves to die](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzEmshVFDzU).

Comment: HAVEN'T YOU SEEN MY MOVIES?!

Comment: hmmm... an angry man, Mace Windu is.

Comment: Mandatory Dave Chappelle clip: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ItxVWTikGI

Answer (score 2):

Can you point to specific examples of posts like this going through?

Because they generally don't already, for a variety of reasons...

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/8451/revisions http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/8455/revisions http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/8456/revisions http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/8468/revisions

Comment: Jeff Atwood, you have a call on line 96189. Jeff Atwood, 96189.

Comment: there is already a warning EULA when people trip the heuristics that goes to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer ; this user is clicking the checkbox and skipping the advice.

Comment: Oh, okay then. Fair enough. I didn't know about that warning.

Comment: is this user still an issue? all caps posts are actually quite exceedingly rare; probably better to treat this as a special case user.

Comment: He's not. All right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8387312/revisions