# Muzzle all-caps shouters

Tags: feature-request, questions, quality-filter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BLOCK QUESTIONS IN ALL CAPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121301/block-questions-in-all-caps)

I just looked through questions by a user who thinks <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is cruise control for cool but forgets that he still needs to steer.

I did a good deed and edited one question, and other people did the same to the other ones.

So here's my feature request: If a question or answer body, outside of quotations or source code blocks, contains more than a certain fraction of all-caps words — over a certain length, so that particles like "I" and abbreviations aren't affected — reject the submission and ask the user not to yell in people's faces.

Comment: "cruise control for cool", made my morning +1