# If a question is in all-uppercase or all-lowercase, our quality filters should automatically reject it

Tags: feature-request, questions, question-quality, quality-filter

## Proposal

If a question on an English-language Stack Exchange site does not contain at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter, our quality filter should reject it.

(We can make exceptions for sites which don't use a mixed-case alphabet, such as [Japanese Language and Usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/).)

## Justification

The quality filter currently rejects neither all-uppercase nor all-lowercase posts. I've checked.

The best Stack Exchange users use mixed case. If an asker is too lazy to use their <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, their question tends not to be of very good quality.

Don't take my word for it. You can see proof. Sam Saffron helped me write [a Stack Exchange Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/355260/all-lowercase-stack-overflow-questions-asked-in-the-last-three-days) which lets you see with your very own eyes that what I am saying is true.

Single-case askers tend to ask poor-quality questions such as:

- ["gem 'websocket-rails' and its scalability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165536/gem-websocket-rails-and-its-scalability)
- [how to set particular value as dropdown default value in edit button click event in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174385/how-to-set-particular-value-as-dropdown-default-value-in-edit-button-click-event)
- [Changing copied arabic text font in document richtexteditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197995/changing-copied-arabic-text-font-in-document-richtexteditor)

In addition, posts which use only uppercase or only lowercase — even if they aren't riddled with typos or grammatical errors — tend to be hard to read. Capitalization aids readability.

## Why is this proposal not a duplicate?

This proposal is not a duplicate of the older proposal ["BLOCK QUESTIONS IN ALL CAPS"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121301/block-questions-in-all-caps). This is because it also deals with all-lowercase questions.

**All-lowercase questions are 50 times more common than all-caps questions.**  Stack Overflow gets only about 100 all-uppercase questions per year; see [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508338/all-uppercase-stack-overflow-questions-asked-in-the-last-30-days).  Yet it gets about 5,000 all-lowercase questions per year; see [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/355260/all-lowercase-stack-overflow-questions-asked-in-the-last-three-days). (These statistics are for Stack Overflow only; the rest of our network wasn't considered.)

I suspect that the older proposal was declined for two reasons:

1. All-uppercase questions are rare.
2. Therefore, the effort required to block all-uppercase questions is too much.

This proposal is better. For just a bit more effort, the Stack Exchange developers can get a much richer reward.

## Conclusion

What do you think of my proposal?

Agree? Disagree? Thoughts?

PS: This idea is modified and adapted from [an older idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121301/block-questions-in-all-caps#123408) by Stack Exchange user Gilles. My dear sir Gilles, I thank you.

## Note

There's even a [chat bot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) which automatically detects questions with all-caps titles and alerts interested users and moderators.

Comment: I was so tempted to edit your test question ;)

Comment: yEs it Is DupE, somEone migHT aSk to BloCk QuestioNS wiTh ranDom CaSE.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Random-case questions are much harder to detect programmatically. The developers could block such questions if they really wanted to, but it probably wouldn't be worth the effort.

Comment: @nicael:  1.  The [all-caps test question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264267/this-post-is-just-a-test-please-ignore-it) which I created then deleted? Ha :)

Comment: @nicael:  2.  Is my proposal truly a duplicate, even considering the sentence of my proposal which starts with the words, "This is because it also"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard:  Is my proposal truly a duplicate, even considering the sentence of my proposal which starts with the words, "This is because it also"?

Comment: Yes it is duplicate no matter how you paint it. Asking to filter out or block content based on the words casing is the same.

Comment: Update added a year later:  Stack Overflow gets about 5,000 all-lowercase questions per year, according to a [newer meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280906/all-lowercase-questions-are-50-times-more-common-than-all-caps-questions-and-ar). But even those 5,000 questions constitute nothing but "a drop in the ocean", according to some [chat posts](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5066498#5066498) by JamesENL and Quill. Therefore, perhaps it wouldn't be worth the developers' time to configure the quality filters to catch them.