# All-lowercase questions are 50 times more common than all-caps questions, and are often low-quality questions. Let's block them.​

Tags: feature-request, questions, question-quality, quality-filter

First, someone [proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121301/block-questions-in-all-caps) blocking all-caps questions.  This was declined.  The decliner seemed to feel that the problem was too rare to bother with.

Well, **all-lowercase questions are 50 times more common than all-caps questions.**  Stack Overflow gets only about 100 all-uppercase questions per year; see [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508338/all-uppercase-stack-overflow-questions-asked-in-the-last-30-days).  Yet it gets about 5,000 all-lowercase questions per year; see [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/355260/all-lowercase-stack-overflow-questions-asked-in-the-last-three-days). (These statistics are for Stack Overflow only; the rest of our network wasn't considered.)

All-lowercase questions are often of poor quality.  Let's block them.

**Note:  If you disagree with my idea, it would be helpful if you could please tell me *why* you disagree.**

<sub>P.S.  This idea is modified and adapted from [an older idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121301/block-questions-in-all-caps#123408) by stack exchange user Gilles.  My dear sir Gilles, I thank you.</sub>

Comment: Why did you reask the same exact question?

Comment: @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy: This time, unlike last time, I made sure to point out the fact that all-lowercase questions are 50 times more common than all-caps questions. Last time, I neglected to do so, thereby making my proposal much weaker.

Comment: That's an excellent reason to *edit* a question. It is *not* a reason to *reask* it. At all.

Comment: @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy: I hear you. Anyway, even 5,000 questions per year constitute nothing but "a drop in the ocean", according to some [chat posts](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5066498#5066498) by JamesENL and Quill, and so perhaps it wouldn't be worth the developers' time to configure the quality filters to catch them.

Answer (score -1):

**Agree**

I ran [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/355260/all-lowercase-stack-overflow-questions-asked-in-the-last-three-days), then clicked the first ten results.  This showed me ten different recent all-lowercase questions.

None of the questions had a vote total of more than zero.  Many had negative vote totals.  [One question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126645/how-to-update-a-text-file-with-2-iterations-and-both-iterations-should-update-us) even had **nine downvotes** on it.

**All-lowercase questions tend to be of poor quality,** and we should block them.