# Why is the delete notice is above, instead of below the close notice?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40791312/3853934) the delete notice is above, instead of below the close notice. Why is this happening? I understand this was made on purpose, but would like to know the reasoning.

[image]

Comment: I see a more crucial bug here. Why did the quality filter not block that post, thus wasting four users' (of which one is a moderator) time taking care of it?

Comment: @dorukayhan You can ask that as a separate question (and probably it would be better to ask that on Meta Stack Overflow instead of here).

Comment: From quick look now, the delete notice appears above the close notice on all closed questions that are also deleted. Since I can't remember how it used to be before, can't tell if it changed or was always like that. Personally, I find it better this way, since the "main" event is the deletion.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I remember that the delete notice used to be below the close notice.

Comment: I also cannot comment as to whether it at one point was or was not above or below. That said, it makes more sense to show things in sequential order. First comes the question, then comes closure, then deletion, then rage-quit (that's what the comments are for)

Comment: Removed the "support" tag, as what exactly is the support issue here? Removed the "bug" tag, as - what's the bug here? This is how the notices are on **all** questions that have been closed and deleted. I will not debate whether the order is right or not - it is entirely subjective, and as Shadow Wizard commented, the more important bits of information are presented first.

Comment: @dorukayhan you might be interested in this recent feature request: [Disallow entire questions from being entirely bold, italic, ALL CAPS or linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286930/165773)

Comment: @Oded I tagged it with [bug], because the order of notices used to be different.

Comment: @Gothdo irrespective of whether this is different or not, I would consider a bug to indicate that things were *worse* - if the order was not previously an acceptance criterion, then its changing is *not* a bug. And why does it matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delete notice appears above the close notice on all closed questions that are also deleted, and this is on purpose, as Stack Exchange developer confirmed in comments.

The reasoning, at least as I see it, is the importance of things.

When a question is deleted, that's what matters most, the fact it's also closed is less important.

Comment: Does this happen on all the questions?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes; see [Oded's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287378/why-is-the-delete-notice-is-above-instead-of-below-the-close-notice#comment932485_287378): "This is how the notices are on all questions that have been closed and deleted".