# Please put more thought into migrating questions to other stack exchange sites

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please don't migrate low-quality questions to other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites)

https://serverfault.com/questions/252129/which-language-to-use-forintermediary-server

This is an example of a question that is talking about programming language choices, which makes it a subjective stackoverflow question that probably ought to be closed, yet it was migrated to server fault so that we could close it for you.

I know serverfault regulars keep raising this issue over poor quality server questions that should have been closed rather than migrated but when stack overflow starts migrating *programming* questions to other sites then things have gone from bad to absurd.

I appreciate that on a site as large as SO this is difficult to police, but you guys really need to get a grip on this. Not only is it annoying for the other sites but migrating questions just so they can be closed on other sites is hardly going to endear any of us to new visitors, is it?

Comment: If only things had changed since that last question.

Comment: I agree, that one shouldn't have been migrated, but do we need to bring this up every single time?  "Put more thought into it" isn't much of a solution proposal (not a new one, at least).  Come up with a feature request that will help people decide when to migrate, or just stop them from doing it.

Comment: Just flag the question at both ends. The original so that a mod can clear the migration history and deal with it more appropriately and the migrated one so that a mod can delete it.

Comment: What @Bill says. This is bound to happen occasionally, and complaining on Meta will not do much to educate the closevoting masses. Maybe we need hard numbers to support or discard the discussion. Is it possible to query SEDE to find questions that have been migrated and then closed on the target site?

Comment: It IS happening more than "occasionally" though. I was willing to accept that for a while, as noted on the original question. Thing is though, it's NOT just occasionally any more. It's *becoming normal* to close several bad quality migrated questions a day.

Comment: @Pekka - I'm a very low rep user here on stack overflow. While I agree with Bill's comment that it would be better to propose solutions than merely complain, it's very difficult for us on Server Fault to "educate the masses" on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Robert yeah, I see the dilemma. I think the only thing we, as SO users, *can* do is add a comment when a question has gained migrate votes while it should be closed as not a real question. I do that occasionally, but paying attention to what close reasons others chose is nothing the system encourages. I'll try to pay more attention to it

Comment: based on Pekka's and Bill's comments on this question, I've proposed a solution http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84839/should-moving-offtopic-questions-to-other-stack-exchange-sites-cost-reputation which might or might not be useful.

Comment: When's the last time a server fault person has said something nice on MSO?

Comment: @Andrew Grim - perhaps I'm mis-understanding you but what have I said here that wasn't "nice"? I appreciate that I'm biased in how I see myself but I think what I've said here and in my follow-on question has been polite and an attempt to be constructive.

Comment: @Robert: In the comment, I was meaning to say that SF were being negative, not that they were being incivil. But +1 for trying to suggest a solution - maybe I missed it while reading the question last night.

Comment: @Andrew - no worries. And yes its probably true we're mostly negative when we visit here, sorry :-( I guess that most of our visits have been to fix what we perceive as problems rather than to make the sites better in their own right. Which is a bit of a shame.