# Moving instead of closing

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was this question closed as off-topic without being migrated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960986/latex-for-mac-lion-2011-how-to-add-cls-file) does make sense, it should have been moved to tex.stackexchange.com. I am pretty sure the OP would have gotten a good answer there.

Comment: As a general rule, only high-quality, recent questions get migrated. The question you're referring to is recent, but doesn't ask a specific (i.e. SE-appropriate) question, so it doesn't qualify.

Comment: You could always flag it with a custom reason explaining that it should be moved to [tex.se] (and why)

Comment: Yeah, your example question is not a great one. Had it been better, it probably *would* have been migrated.  Note that the close reason is *"Not a Real Question,"* not *"Off-Topic."*

Comment: Well the user could have been asked to edit the question a bit.

Comment: "Don't migrate crap." As a personal aside, I almost never vote to migrate. Question quality is generally poor. Absent that, I tend to assume the question already exists on the target site. If it's a useful question, I might *suggest* researching if the question fits on [insert site name here] and leave it up to the user to actually do it.

Comment: Questions that may qualify as _crap_ on [so] don't necessarily have to be _crap_ on other [se] sites, especially the smaller, more specialized ones.

Comment: +1 consider this a blind faith in a judgement of [hi-rep active tex oldtimer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/243/patrick-gundlach) if you wish

Comment: I have flagged the question for migration and I have also cast a reopen vote on the question in case the flag gets declined.

Comment: And that's fine. If the moderator wants to (or even has a duty to) review the question, review the FAQ at the target site, consider duplicates that may be present, then sure, let him/her migrate it. I consider it a courtesy, not an obligation. At any rate, a comment has been present on the question for days suggesting an alternate site. The user has had ample time to conduct such a review himself. If it is important to the user to get an answer, the user has all the opportunity in the world to make that happen.

Comment: So [this was finally moved](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42309/9646), but closed as a dupe of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252/9646).  The morals of the story? a) nothing is different under the sun (the system works) and b) better to hold off on a migration than to migrate crap/the wrong thing prematurely.

Comment: Well as we all know a dupe isn't necessarily bad. Also, yes you may be right, migrating prematurely is not good but I feel that just closing a question is not the answer either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As gnat correctly [points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120301/moving-instead-of-closing#comment317963_120301), you are a veteran Tex.SE user and an official Tex.SE representative, which isn't immediately obvious. If *you* say the question is welcome over there, I think we can safely assume that is the case. I'm sure a mod will migrate it soon.

Still, in general, please understand that we are very careful with off-topic migrations away from SO because low-quality migrations have (rightly) resulted in angry feedback from the <strike>victim</strike> target sites in the past. See e.g. [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) or [Please put more thought into migrating questions to other stack exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84834/please-put-more-thought-into-migrating-questions-to-other-stack-exchange-sites)

I think in the end, a careful migration policy is doing more good than harm. Users can always re-ask on the right site in such cases.

Comment: I think that [programmers.se] is a special case here. It is not really specialized if you ask me, at least not compared to [tex.se].

Comment: @The yeah, but I *have* seen angry feedback from other sites, too, e.g. [Please put more thought into migrating questions to other stack exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84834)

Comment: Whee, so many comments and answers :) If I remember correctly, I have flagged this question as "off topic", but I couldn't give it a correct destination. I really thank all for your comments, it gives me a good feeling that I should have written a slightly longer comment _why_ it is welcome on tex.stackexchange.

Comment: @Patrick: [The highly restricted migration options](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77264/157556) have been one of my personal pet peeves for ages.

Answer (score 4):

It's not at all obvious to someone with no TeX experience that this is a legitimate question about using TeX-related tools, and not a poor-quality, didn't-do-the-research question. In such cases, please flag the question to ask for a migration, making it clear that you're a regular on the target site (check that the asker hasn't reposted first).