# Is asking for a general description/categorization/classification of a tool on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I stumbled on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453161/whats-is-vista-4gl/20907465#20907465) that basically ask 'What type of tool is X'.

Is this on-topic based on this bullet from the help-center

> •software tools commonly used by programmers

Looking at the answers on the question at hand you have to stretch 'commonly'.

Based on answers here:
[Asking if certain tools contain certain features?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185055/asking-if-certain-tools-contain-certain-features)
[Any way to ask about the objective existence of a library/tool for a specialized programming task?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172602/any-way-to-ask-about-the-objective-existence-of-a-library-tool-for-a-specialized)
[Are SO questions about general-purpose tools off-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125524/are-so-questions-about-general-purpose-tools-off-topic)

I could argue that this question is a corner-case for it's on-topic-ness.

I voted to close with reason 'asking for off-site resource' but I'm unsure if that is correct.
**Should I retract my close-vote?**

<sup>note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20907465/578411) is flagged as not answer which is invalid</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only my opinion as I believe this is the first such question I have encountered, but I do not think the question is off-topic.  It might not be an ideal SO question, but I don't think it needs to be closed.

1. As you stated, it is about a software tools commonly used by programmers
2. It is a specific question and is answerable by someone who knows what the language is.
3. It is not asking for a link or a resource, just an explanation.
4. Is it not something easily found via Google (given the fact that googling Vista 4GL now returns that question as the first result)

As I mentioned, this is just my 2 cents, so don't make a choice solely on my thoughts unless my argument was convincing enough.

That being said, and given the question <s>now has 4 close votes</s> is now closed, I don't think it is worth reopening since it is not a fantastic question and there are plenty of answers that seem to address the question (I say seem to because I am only assuming the answers are accurate).  But it would be nice to ensure it doesn't get deleted after it is closed since it *could* have some future value.