# Is it okay to raise multiple flags in a row, or is that considered abusive?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, flags

My situation:

- Maybe once a week I go on patrol of things that need to be flagged and cleaned up (migrated, closed, etc.)
- A common thing I do is look through the Ubuntu, Linux, OS X tags (as it seems many of these questions are often better suited for Ask ubuntu, Super User, Server Fault, etc.)
- Often, I may flag several in a row (like 5 in under a minute)
- I've never had more than 10 awaiting review either. That's a limit I've imposed on myself.

My questions:

1. Is there a known time constraint for flagging as to not appear as being abusive or anything else I should be aware of? (I know there is a limit to the number of flags per day, although I've never reached it)
2. If the vast majority of the flags are helpful, is this even an issue? Should I not worry about it since it is in no way abuse?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a known time constraint for flagging as to not appear as being abusive or anything else I should be aware of? (I know there is a limit to the number of flags per day, although I've never reached it)

I doubt it. The number of flags should be enough of a limit.

> If the vast majority of the flags are helpful, is this even an issue? Should I not worry about it since it is in no way abuse?

No, it's not abusive in any way, and we thank you for raising these helpful flags!

If there's something that you're not sure is helpful or considerate to flag about, you can always raise an "other..." flag and ask us, or better yet post here on meta and we'll answer it (so others can learn).

Also, when one or more of your flags is declined, be sure to **read the decline reason** — often there'll be an explanation as to how you flagged wrongly, how you should be flagging instead, and so on. (Not always, but you get the idea.)

Comment: That said, one flag *not* to use in bulk is "very low quality". Frankly I find the VLQ flag pretty silly, and many people who flag posts VLQ *en masse* really have better things to do but are just plain lazy.

Comment: Right, I agree. That helps a lot. When I do bulk flag it is really only for migration purposes so the question can receive better attention and be placed with the appropriate community/site.

Comment: @TryTryAgain: Ah, about migration - I should mention that you should *not* flag old questions (at least a year old, if not at least 6 months) or answered questions or bad questions for migration. If they're egregiously off-topic, flag/vote as "off topic". See also: [Please don't migrate low-quality questions to other sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites)