# Does Stack Overflow support gracefully moving an off topic question somewhere more appropriate?

Tags: feature-request, off-topic

There are quite a few "off-topic" questions on Stack Overflow that are flagged, stopped, voted down, and so on, which nevertheless have very useful information for me.  Some have solved problems for me and I would even want to add a comment or reply.

Is there a graceful way to migrate these threads somewhere else so that they may continue to live, without cluttering up the main Stack Overflow site with "off-topic" questions?

Comment: So like an SO bin?

Comment: yes, there are places where they can 'continue to live', your PC for example. Or if you prefer, you can put them in another website (giving proper attribution). Remember that `"user contributions are licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required"`

Comment: Do you mean new questions or old? I ask because old questions get the historical lock. New questions l ike this are really bad for the site as a whole as described [Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Answer (score 1):

We already have a feature known as migration.

3k users can vote to migrate offtopic posts to a certain subset of all the sites. Diamond moderators can migrate to *any* site. Just flag the post with a custom flag, saying "migrate to X.stackexchange.com". (List of all sites [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#name))

BUT:

- This doesn't mean that there is always a site to migrate to. The network clearly doesn't cover all topics, so many questions may just be off topic--no migration needed.
- If the question is a programming question and off topic on SO (and Programmers), then it is mort probably just off topic. SO+Programmers don't handle *all* programming questions, it is restricted by the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). This applies to any destination migration site. Many a time, mods have to discuss with the mods of the destination site before migrating--so a question may not be migrated due to the site scope. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461619/can-diablo-3-be-run-through-wine-on-linux) *may* be on-topic on Gaming, but I highly doubt it.
- [We do not migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites/82986#82986). Some questions may be on-topic elsewhere, but if they're not too good they don't get migrated. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365495/network-security) *may* be on topic for secutiry.se--but it is not-constructive, and thus won't be migrated. There are also questions which would be tolerated if asked on the destination site directly, would probably not be migrated if asked elsewhere.  Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460589/update-linux-dns-resolver-ip-for-different-host). Maybe on topic for our Unix&Linux site, but not too good.

Comment: We also (generally) don't migrate old stuff

Comment: Also, when in doubt, the Moderators ping the other site's moderators and ask them if they even want the question.  Users *should not* cross post a post to multiple sites.