# What should I do with Android-related questions that have nothing to do with writing Android apps?

Tags: discussion, migration, android

Alright, so on Stack Overflow, I keep coming across Android-related questions in my review queue. They don't really have anything to do with writing Android apps *per se*, but more of a "Halp, my phone broke, how can I fix it?"-type question.  So my question is should these be moved to another site? Super User? Is there a mobile dedicated site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We generally don't migrate questions if they're:

- really old
- low quality
- already answered
- would be closed on the target site anyways

So, if the question is relatively new, is answerable, and you think it would be a good fit on another site, go for it. Android phone related questions would likely be directed towards [Android.SE](http://android.stackexchange.com).

If it does meet those non-migration criteria, chances are the target site wouldn't want the question or even be able to do anything with it, so migrating it doesn't solve any problems. Just vote to close it and be on your way, since it's clearly off-topic here.

Comment: ["The golden rule of question migration: never migrate crap!"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites/82986#82986)