# How to flag for migration to serverfault?

Tags: support, migration, serverfault

When I flag a post I can't seem to flag it to migrate to serverfault.com.

Strange I can flag it to

```
     belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com
     belongs on superuser.com
     belongs on tex.stackexchange.com
     belongs on dba.stackexchange.com
     belongs on sharepoint.stackexchange.com
```

These are the only options I get ?

Any reason for that. How do you migrate to ServerFault?

Comment: Yeah. I could do that. But it seems rather odd to. I mean if these sites are given shouldn't they just give everything on Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Aarthi No idea what you're talking about ;)

Comment: @Yannis NINJA!!!

Comment: @CarlSaldanha All 95 SE sites? That wouldn't really make sense, what are the chances of an ontopic Bicycles.SE question getting asked on StackOverflow?

Comment: Maybe show these first and give an option for more??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flag for moderation attention and ask for migration to Server Fault, the off topic list only includes Meta and the four most common migration targets. Keep in mind that questions that are on topic on Stack Overflow will not be migrated, even if they are on topic on an other site, and that [sub par questions will not be migrated in general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites).

Lastly; [migration for questions older than 60 days is disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) (even for moderators).

Comment: How "most common" is evaluated? sharepoint and tex more common than serverfault and unix ?

Comment: @guido 10K+ rep users and moderators have access to migration stats, that tell you how many questions have been migrated away, and how many of these migrations were rejected (closed at the target site).