# Forward posts to relevant groups

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggest alternate forum/exchange when “off-topic”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161761/suggest-alternate-forum-exchange-when-off-topic)

Many posts are posted only in **stackoverflow**. Some of them are closed because they are not relevant to stackoverflow. In that case moderators should redirect to it's corresponding sites like 'codereview.stackexchange.com', 'webapps.stackexchange.com'. By that way you can attract more audience to those sites and make user happy. But these redirects should be handled with care OR moderators should suggest one or more sites that are relevant to that question before closing them.

Answer (score 6):

This is already being done.

Posts that are off-topic on one site, but are new enough (younger than 60 days) and of *sufficient quality* can be migrated to a site where they are on-topic.

Note the *sufficient quality* part though. The target site moderators are consulted before a migration and can reject posts.

For a (very limited) list of target sites, users can vote to migrate a question that is deemed off-topic on one site but is on-topic for another. If enough users vote it'll be migrated automatically. The target site can still opt to close the question on the other side though.

For all other target sites, flag a post for moderator attention if you feel it is worthy of being migrated. Use the 'other' option, and explain what site it should be migrated to and why.

Comment: who will do this migration? As a user, i am not seeing these kind of process. What other users are doing is, they just down-vote and close that post eventhough that has sufficient quality.

Comment: @user10: moderators do most of these. When 'regular' flag a post as off-topic, they can suggest a migration, but only for a limited number of sites; only when enough people vote for such a migration is the migration automatic. You can flag a post for moderator attention (use the 'other' option) to request a migration to a specific site.

Comment: @user10: most posts do *not* have sufficient quality.

Comment: @martijin something is not really perfect with down voting. Take this post as an example. I really don't know this feature is already there. I am using stackoverflow almost an year and i haven't seen this feature. So i just posted here. But i got 2 down votes.You should think little more about down vote AND up vote.

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. People are voting on your feature request, and perhaps downvote because your question shows a lack of prior research.

Comment: @user10 Migration happens a less often than it used to because many recipient sites have complained that most posts Stack Overflow migrated to them were either poor quality or also off-topic for their site.

Comment: @user10 I think you are getting downvotes precisely because you have been here over a year and were unaware that this feature already exists, especially because it happens a LOT and is frequently discussed on meta.