# Users should be required to leave custom comments when closing a question

Tags: discussion

It does not make sense that you can put a question on hold without an explanation.

StackOverflow is a great resource but the way in which users wield their power leads to a lot of frustration and anger on the part of the users.

I believe Stack would be more successful if it was required that a user leave a comment in the On Hold question with information about where a question should be asked and specifically why it was put on hold.

My question is why is this not a requirement of users?

Example Question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384627/need-resources-for-deciding-between-adobe-edge-flash-createjs-for-animation

Comment: Do you have an example of an on-hold question with no explanation?

Comment: There is already an explanation of each "on hold" reason attached to the question.

Comment: @Ray - There is a stock example. What I suggest is they should take 15 seconds to address the specifics or suggest an alternate venue for the question.

Comment: @Chris - I added this as per your request.

Comment: The example question has a comment regarding placing the question on hold that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...". The second sentence of the question is "What I want are links to information to help me to make an informed decision". So how is the close reason invalid?

Comment: No moderator was involved in that closure. All regular users

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you are looking for.  The text in the question you cited provides information required to edit the question and make it more appropriate.

Comment: It's 2013.  Do we really not have pattern matching ability to nuke questions like this before they even exist?!?!

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi - With the amount of flags that are currently in the close queue, I'm not sure if the moderators or other users can spare 15 seconds to write, frankly, what will be copied and pasted as repeat reasons.

Comment: @CarlVeazey: I don't argue that the question is invalid. It may well be. I argue that a user deserves more information than an automated response. Otherwise the On Hold status seems too easy to place and frustrating for someone who took the time to carefully word a question.

Comment: Stack Overflow gets 7,000 new questions every day, many (most?) of them garbage and/or not good fits for the site. Providing a custom-tailored explanation for each is simply not possible.

Comment: What more information do you want @GuidoAnselmi?

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi - To reply to your new addition, downvotes in Meta only indicate that the voter disagrees with your proposal/POV.

Comment: Related: [Suggest alternate forum/exchange when off-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161761)

Comment: @ChrisForrence: Thanks. I did not understand that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're referring to [this question of yours that was recently put on hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384627/need-resources-for-deciding-between-adobe-edge-flash-createjs-for-animation):

there's already a text box below your question that says exactly why it was put on hold:

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." – John Conde, BigDave, KatieK
>   If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment.

These users are not moderators, they're normal users.  The only 'moderators' you see on the site are people with diamonds next to their name, like me.

To answer the question you ask -- there is **nowhere** on the Stack Exchange network that is a good place to answer your question.

We're not a substitute for sites that give recommendations. Opinions are like... armpits -- everyone has them, and they stink.  That's why we don't specialize in opinions (recommendations) we specialize in answers to specific questions.

I recommend Slashdot, Hacker News, or Reddit for your question. Maybe twitter?  There's a newfangled comparison site out there called [Slant.co](http://slant.co), this may even be on topic there (I don't really know, but it seems like it could be, if asked correctly).

To address the question you just edited in about "why the downvotes":

People voted you down for a few reasons

1. They disagree with your position (that users should have to write custom comments)
2. they likely disagree with the tone in which you expressed that opinion and
3. You received quite a few downvotes before editing an example into your question -- people downvote when arguments are not cogent or complete.

Comment: Thanks. However that is a stock answer. If SO is the wrong place to go with this question it would be nice for someone to give me a suggestion for where is the right place to go.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi That's really something you should figure out.

Comment: Moderators like George don't have enough hours in the day to leave custom comments.  The stock comment in this case explains exaclty what the problem was.  Why is that not good enough?

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi: Sure, it would be *nice*, but I hardly think it should be required. "Where should I ask this question" is no more on-topic for Stack Overflow than recommendation questions.

Comment: My armpits don't stink! How dare you... *sniff* Oh, wait...

Comment: @George: I appreciate your good will. My real wish is that more people who are down voting these questions, respected the users enough to add additional information thoughtfully as you have here.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi I've updated my answer with specific places where you could ask such a question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Thank you George and I appreciate your service as a moderator.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Was MetaStackOverflow the right venue for me to ask this question? (The question on this page). I don't understand the now 10 down votes.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi Meta was the right venue. People voted you down for a few reasons 1) They disagree with your position (that users should have to write custom comments) 2) they likely disagree with the tone in which you expressed that opinion and 3) you received quite a few downvotes before editing an example into your question -- people downvote when arguments are not cogent or complete.

Comment: My custom comment would always be: "I voted to close."

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: That seems strange to me. To express disagreement with my position I would think they should answer the question itself rather than downvote the question. The question itself seems like a valid question and worth considering.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi when people come with unique discussions and feature requests, there are usually comments and/or answers explaining, in addition to downvotes.  However, your discussion/feature request, is a common one so generally people dislike rehashing the same conversation.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Any chance up your reopening the original question? I have worked with another more senior user to make it more palatable to the SO community.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi I made an edit and voted to re-open it, along with three other users.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Thank you George. For what it's worth, you and my senior user friend have restored my faith in SO.

Comment: And yet an hour later it was closed again. I think some people on SO are far too trigger happy when it comes to closing questions. This seemed like a perfectly reasonable question to me (at least in its current state).

Answer (score 6):

The reason is added automatically by the system, including links for more information.

For example, the text on the question you linked to says:

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> - "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." – John Conde, BigDave, KatieK
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the 
>   [help center](/help/closed-questions), please [edit the question](/posts/18384627/edit) or leave a comment.

Besides, "on hold" is meant to be a temporary state in many cases. If the question can be edited into something that fits the site rules, it can be reopened by the community.