# What is an Appropriate Question for Meta Stack Overflow if not this?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, meta, scope

I received quite a few downvotes for [a question I just asked here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194356/users-should-be-required-to-leave-custom-comments-when-closing-a-question). If not here, where was I supposed to ask this question?

Comment: [How do I participate in Meta Stack Overflow and not die trying](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying)

Comment: Voting on Meta can be a little odd to begin with, where generally people downvoted both bad or off topic questions as well as ones where they disagreed with the proposed change. It sounds like that might change, based on this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193781/scope-of-mso-unique-voting-policy , but people still downvote for both of those reasons.

Comment: @BradLarson don't forget how people respond to well trod subjects

Comment: I downvoted that one for the lack of research. This kind of request has been discussed a number of times and the answer tends to be: **no, not a good feature**.

Comment: You're confusing downvotes with closure. Questions get *closed* because they're asked in the wrong place. Downvotes have a different and very wide-ranging meaning.

Comment: As an aside once you have the dupe, you can see the [other questions that are also linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/29531?lq=1) The 16 dupes (excluding yours) have votes between -6 and -15.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an appropriate question for Meta. It's just that people disagree with you (i. e. they don't find your feature request useful or necessary).

Just to clarify your doubt:

> A down vote = disagreement? I thought a down vote = bad question.

For a long time, downvotes on Meta expressed disagreement. This has been changed recently, but it is [still the case for `feature-request` questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193884/a-proposal-for-more-constructive-downvoting-on-meta-express-disagreement-by-ans). "Downvote == bad question" is for other non-feature-requests and for every question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: A down vote = disagreement? I thought a down vote = bad question.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi For a long time, downvotes on Meta expressed disagreement. This has been changed, but it is [still the case for `feature-request` questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193884/a-proposal-for-more-constructive-downvoting-on-meta-express-disagreement-by-ans). "Downvote == bad question" is for other non-feature-requests and for every question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @H2CO3 How people are voting has not really changed.  The help center text explaining how people vote has been updated to (attempt to) better *explain* how people are *already* voting.

Comment: @Servy You're right, it has not been changed yet. But the proposal's goal, if I understand correctly, is to actually have people change their voting habits.

Comment: @H2CO3 When posts aren't making a proposal there really isn't anything to agree/disagree with.  The problem was with people posting "downvotes are just different on meta" in response to an OP complaining about downvotes to a poorly research, unclear, and/or not constructive post.  This just caused confusion for all involved since the downvotes never were for disagreement to begin with.

Answer (score 16):

People voted you down for a few reasons

1. They disagree with your position (that users should have to write custom comments)
2. They likely disagree with the tone in which you expressed that opinion and
3. You received quite a few downvotes before editing an example into your question -- people downvote when arguments are not cogent or complete.
4. Your question was a common duplicate. Since Meta has a good searching system (And Google is pretty good too), we expect people to see if their question has been asked before.  Since that didn't happen, people downvoted your question.

Comment: +1 - I think that #4 was the largest contributor.