# How to handle unfitting questions, when there is no place to ask them?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked this [question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/18778/what-does-adulterated-mean-and-why-is-it-so-dangerous) on homebrewing and it was put on hold as off-topic. That's okay for me, because I expected that. No exchange seems to be a good fit for this one. This was the reason for asking it there, because it is at least a bit related to brewing.

How should I proceed with this question, because I still want to know an answer, but struggling to find the correct place for it.

How to handle questions, which do not fit perfectly, but have no other place to be asked?

Comment: Very related: [Suggest alternate forum/exchange when "off-topic"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161761/suggest-alternate-forum-exchange-when-off-topic)

Comment: It's related but covers a different topic IMHO

Comment: Ok, I'll retract the flag.  Maybe someone else can find a better dupe.

Comment: Does it relate specifically to alcohol? Seems like possibly a good fit for [alcohol.se].

Comment: Gave it a try xD will report if it worked :P

Comment: Looks like a popular question. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible that there are questions that aren't a good fit for any Stack Exchange site.

**That's ok.**

There are other sites, reddit, Quora, or even a simple google search which can lead to your answer.

If a question is off-topic, it should be closed and remain closed.

Comment: Don't forget that if it's a broad enough subject, there's always Area 51.

Answer (score -1):

You might try posting on [Beer, Wine & Spirits](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com) as your question pertains to *schnapps* which is an alcohol.

Before you do check what is on topic [there](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: These negative votes require explanation.

Comment: Not my downvote but the question isn't asking where this question is on topic... It's asking what to do when questions don't seem to have an appropriate site. As such, this doesn't answer that question.... Which is precisely why I made it a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: The question was where to get the answer and I answered that.  If someone downvoted because the answer would be found in the other community then I don't know how to answer the question.  I'll give it another while and then delete my answer unless I get an explanation how my answer does not answer the question.   If you need a quote of the question: "because I still want to know an answer, but struggling to find the correct place for it."  The subject is schnapps.  I thought the proper community would be alcohol.