# When to migrate a question

Tags: discussion, migration, migrated-questions

I suggest creating a definite ***list of guidelines for when to migrate questions*** from one site to another and adding it to the *Community Wiki*. I didn't find it in one place.

If I'm wrong, please point me to that place.

Comment: Why is this necessary? Most sites have guidelines when it comes to receiving and sending questions to and from other sites anyway. If you need information, look at the sites involved. Meta already has general guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

The following guidelines could be suggested:

1. [Do not migrate bad questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82986) (golden rule). Close it.
2. If the question have attracted some interest and have some answers, do not migrate. If not, close it as Off-topic.
3. If the question is suggested to migrate in comments, have no answers -> migrate.
4. [Do not migrate old questions with answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).