# How do I migrate a question to a more appropriate SE site?

Tags: support, migration

[I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59760789/580412) on SO and someone has pointed out (via a close vote) that it would be better suited to Super User.

I agree.  Let's move the question.  How do I do that?

A minute or two of looking through the UI and meta doesn't seem to have the answer.

Comment: I suppose.
"In order for the question to be migrated, at least three of the close votes must be for migration to the same site."
That's lame.  I would rather simply be more proactive than wait around for the remaining votes to (maybe) appear.

Comment: @phs Did you read πάντα ῥεῖ's answer?

Comment: As a SU mod... that feels like a better fit for serverfault :D

Comment: It had [a single close vote](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59760789/timeline) which expired, and it's sitting at -2: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82941/282094

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I agree. Let's move the question. How do I do that?

Are you a moderator on that site? If not you could flag for mod attention and propose the site to migrate with your flagging reason.

Site moderators or CMs can migrate questions to other sites single handedly.

---

> I asked a question on SO and someone has pointed out (via a close vote) that it would be better suited to Super User.

In your particular case, you can simply copy body and title of your question, reask it at SE Super User, and delete your original question at SO.
The latter is important to avoid cross-posting.

IIRC SE Super User is a site listed in the standard close reasons to migrate a question at SO. Thus you can vote yourself for migration selecting that site, but that won't have an immediate effect to get your question migrated, it still needs five (or is it three meanwhile for SO?) users to migrate your question, so you have to wait<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1)</sup>
<sub>There are good reasons for this: Not all folks with CV powers participating the original site, might also have good in depth knowledge what's *on-topic* at the proposed target site.

We've even seen cases where site moderators or CMs got that wrong.</sub>

Comment: In any case, There is no benefit to migrating and there is a significant downside in that the whole process is more complicated and the question retains its original date, so if you asked it yesterday it will be shown on the new target site (e.g. Super User) as having been asked yesterday. It is always better to just delete and repost on the new site.

Comment: @terdon And that's what I primarily suggested for the particular case.

Comment: The benefit is that your typical user might actually do that for you.  Asking them to manually copy-pasta between sites is a bad experience.

Comment: I know, and that's why I upvoted. I just wanted to make it clear to the OP, not to you, that migrating is pointless. There are no benefits to migrating and there are some downsides.

Comment: @phs migration requires either 4 users and an existing migration path or a mod. And, even if it happens, your question will appear as old so it won't be shown as though it had just been asked. Copying it is quite easy, I mean it's Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C and then Ctrl+V on the target site, and most importantly you can do it yourself and your question will appear fresh and clean on the target. Migration is just a headache for everyone involved the way it currently works.