# Why was my question (relating to algorithms that work with many-core Opterons) closed as being "off topic"?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I posted this question:

[Why are my Opteron cores running at only 75% capacity each? (25% CPU idle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738991/why-are-my-opteron-cores-running-at-only-75-capacity-each-25-cpu-idle)

It was closed for being "off topic" by "some, Jim Garrison, Kris, Frank van Puffelen, dgw".  I've studied the FAQ and the question clearly relates to programming and software development. I don't think it's a borderline case, I just think these guys were not paying attention.  I tried contacting them through StackOverflow but got no response from any of them.

Do others agree the question should be reopened?

Comment: `I tried contacting them thru StackOverflow but got no response from any of them.` They are not ignoring you, `@username` comments don't generate inbox notifications for people who haven't posted at least one comment in the question (and editors). Your three comments to the close voters never reached them.

Comment: looks like a case of [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773) when first reviewer makes a slippery guess and others just blindly follow

Answer (score 7):

I didn't see the question before, but I have a couple of guesses.

Your question concerns two things. The first one is the configuration of your server. If the problem is in it (I'm not too good with server software/hardware, so please excuse my ignorance), maybe in it's configuration or something, then the question is indeed off-topic on SO.

The second point of view is to suspect your own application. In this variant, the question would of course be on topic, but I personally would vote to close it as not a real question (no offense!). Why? Well, because you didn't really provide much information about your application, so guessing about the reasons is like shooting in the dark.

Now, considering the above, let's take a look at the question itself. You say a couple of words about your application, then you describe the server's behavior in much more detail; you even include the dump which itself occupies more space than all the other text in your topic. I believe that those who voted to close your question simply thought that you are mainly asking about what's wrong with *your server*, not *your application*. Thus, they probably (I can't be sure of course, just guessing) thought the question belongs to https://serverfault.com/ rather than SO.