# Question closed for possible duplicate

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049810/sse-uncaught-error-security-err-dom-exception-18) and users with enough reputation points have closed it for `Possible Duplicate` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704929/uncaught-error-security-err-dom-exception-18). Given that the questions are different and so is the answer, the only thing they have in common is the vague error message.

I read the answers posted on the existing post but could not implement them since they are not applicable. In my case there is no `file` that I could call through `localhost` url !!

It is a bit frustrating :)

Comment: Just to correct some terminology - the question was closed by 5 other users with enough reputation to cast close votes. No "administrators" or moderators were involved.

Comment: And I agree - the question and answers are different.

Comment: I have edited the term "administrators" to "users with enough reputation points". Thank you

Comment: Your question is reopened now. I did not read the question, so I'm not implying you did do this,  but to avoid such situations it is important to provide as much (relevant) information as possible.

Comment: Problem is that once one user vote to close others can see it in the moderation tools and sometimes they just follow the first user's lead without really checking for themselves.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I will make question titles much more accurate in the future.

Comment: related: [Herd mentality closure of questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156811/165773), [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773)