# Dynamically update close vote counts

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, live-refresh

Can the close vote count on questions be dynamically updated?

Or is there any specific reason this hasn't been done?

If it's a performance or server load thing, there are new comment and new answer notifications, and these surely are a lot more common than close votes, so that aspect wouldn't really make sense to me.

Example:

[image: close]

## ⇩

Someone, somewhere, casts a close vote.

## ⇩

[image: close (1)]

What I'm more surprised at is that this hasn't been asked before, or maybe I just couldn't find it.

Comment: I saw he was at 995 and those freehand circles compelled me to take him over the edge...

Answer (score 2):

While there may be some potential benefits, I do **NOT** think that it is a good idea.  I have a strong feeling that it would cause some people, who aren't sure whether or not a question should be closed, to vote to close it.  Additionally, it may farther encourage [herd behavior-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_behavior) voting-to-close.

Comment: If one considers closing he'll click the "close" and see the numbers in there anyway. This is just a shortcut.

Comment: wrt herd behavior, see [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773) for a documented case of such a behavior

Comment: This is an argument against showing the close vote number at all

Answer (score 1):

I don't personally see any need for this.

The answers and comments feature has a use, in that if you are in the middle of typing a comment/answer and you get a notification allowing you to see what somebody else has posted, then you can review it and it may cause you to cancel your own post (maybe its a dupe, maybe it clarified something and your answer is now irrelevant)

Whereas, being kept up to date with close votes has no use. You shouldn't need to be reviewing other people votes in order to make your own decision. If you think the question should be closed, then you make the decision to close it. No need to worry what other people think.

SO already handles the fact that if you click "close" and it already has the 5 required votes (or 1 mod vote) then you get notified anyway.

Comment: What about if you're busy typing up an answer and see the close votes streaming in? It may be a good idea to post it before it gets closed, if you wish to do so. Though I have no idea whether this is the correct course of action.

Comment: @Dukeling: While I see your point, in my experience it is usually very obvious when a question is about to be closed. I have had a couple of times where I have gone to post and answer only to be told the question has now been closed, but in honesty, I know I shouldn't have been posting an answer to such a poor question anyway.. sometimes I am just too nice

Comment: @Dukeling - If you are convinced that the close votes are mistaken (and possibly believe that your answer will demonstrate this) then one possible workaround would be to post a stub answer and instantly delete it. You can then edit it and undelete at your leisure. (Though it had better be a good answer or you may incur disapproval for this!)

Comment: @Dukeling if you started typing an answer you can submit it even after the question is closed. Just re-enable the submit button (that get disabled once the question is closed) using the browser dev tools and click it. It works. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd We're probably not supposed to do that, but good to know. I'll see if I can do that next time this happens.

Comment: It was discussed on Meta already and the bottom line was that it's totally acceptable.