# Quick-links on close vote review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, user-interface

*Another* close vote review queue suggestion...

What about making quick-links for the close reasons already voted upon?

This should make it a bit quicker to work through the queue.

Example:

[image]

Obviously these are very brief descriptions of the reasons and thus won't be too useful for users new to voting to close, who aren't too familiar with the reasons - perhaps it should be a 10k (?) privilege, or unlocked after a certain number of close votes / reviews.

This would obviously make it a bit easier for robo-reviewers - being a 10k privilege would hopefully help (are there many 10k+ robo-reviewers?).

Obviously belong on another site and duplicate probably won't work here.

**Update:**

Yeah, display **all** options probably isn't a good idea.

[image]

Comment: NOOO. That's just. Too. Many. Buttons!!!

Comment: But ... one-click voting.

Comment: You'll need to suggest a better GUI than this. What about a popup dialog listing all of the main close reasons together with their descriptions? Of course, a second dialog would appear if you choose off-topic. Of course, with so many options, it should be misclick-resistant. Say, a radio + button system?

Comment: @JanDvorak Updated, although it's probably beyond salvageable.

Comment: OOF. your second suggestion is even worse than the first one IMO. It's two click like the current system, and it's as ugly as the first one.

Comment: @JanDvorak It's 3-5 clicks with plenty of mouse moving and some waiting.

Comment: 3-5? I can count to four. What's the fifth one?

Comment: Close -> off topic -> another site -> the site -> Vote to close.

Comment: True. I hope you don't want to oneclickify this one.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is a good idea in general.

For one thing, I think it makes it too easy to 'fat finger' a wrong close reason, and encourages closing without enough thought. The menu layout is almost certainly designed that way partly to help guide users in choosing a close reason.

That said; something like this could be done in a userscript for someone who really wants to.

Comment: I'm not sure how such userscript would interact with audits, however.

Comment: @JanDvorak Hmmm... good point. It would have to be carefully done to make sure it works with the Review interface in general. That said, my hope would be that the markup/code for reviews doesn't have anything unique to review audits, otherwise we'll see an "automatically highlight review audits" userscript ;)

Comment: Modified my request, although I'm guessing the same reason still applies, and this might encourage picking the wrong reason for a question that should be closed. In response to your answer - one can already 'fat finger' "Leave Open", can't you? Or is that less significant?

Comment: @Dukeling Definitely a good point on the 'fat fingering'. I guess the main point there would be the more buttons, the easier that is to do. But I know I've accidentally clicked "Looks Good" or "Leave Open" before.

Comment: It's way too easy to write an "automatically highlight review audits" userscript. I won't delve into the details, but let's just say the AJAX call to retrieve the next information (which is the obvious thing to hook into when writing such a script) contains certain information that I would expect the server to keep secret to the client machine that, beyond all doubt, reveals if the post being loaded is an audit.

Comment: @JanDvorak I actually sorta figured something like that. That said, I suspect that most people who would know how to do that would also generally find it fairly easy to manually recognize one.

Comment: this post seems to support your concerns: [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773) -- _"...people are agreeing with existing close votes without thoroughly evaluating whether they're accurate."_