# Close-vote badges

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, badge-request

Are there any existing badges for voting to close questions?

If not, why not? We already have review-queue badges, but some of us don't do the review queues and instead rely on the chatroom or the new questions feed and take actions directly. Also, since such users usually cater only to their respective topic questions, the review / close-votes will likely be better in  quality (?) than the regular review queue efforts (no way to filter queues by topic / tag).

Also, as [PM-2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014959/pm-2ring) [pointed out](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/38743374#38743374), we should reward people who put the effort into finding good dupes, and not just with badges: that sort of thing needs to get a rep reward, otherwise [people will simply continue to farm rep by answering dupes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355308/should-i-mod-flag-users-who-repeatedly-answer-a-question-and-then-vote-to-close?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I feel we deserve some badges in this regard. Or at the very least, make the votes count towards the queue badges.

Comment: badges would likely make [Bandwagon effect in close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773) worse than it is now

Comment: @gnat Perhaps it would, so maybe we shouldn't reward closure of bad / off-topic questions, but I do think we need to give people more incentives for dupe hunting.

Answer (score 6):

Before you have close-vote privileges, you have flag-to-close privileges, and if you're flagging things that end up closed, those flags are marked helpful, which will lead to badges.

Once you have close-vote privileges, you are supposed to use them for their own benefit and not as a chore. Review queues can be kind of a bore, but they need to be done, so there's a badge. If you're just using the site and see a thing that needs to close, that's not a chore, it's just a thing that happened. I can't encourage you to do that by offering you a badge. I sure don't say "oh hey, no need to use the review queues, I'll give you review queue badges anyway!" The queues are there to help the lower-traffic tags - and they need the help!

As for the chatroom, imo that's a **terrible** approach. Other people sharing links and telling you to "go get em" is rarely right. I **completely disagree** that a close vote from a C++ expert on a C++ question is higher quality than a close vote from a Perl expert on that same question. The point about our close reasons is they're not really technical: I can't understand you, you didn't include code, you're asking for a whole book or to have your app written, you haven't said what error you're getting, and so on. Those do not require expertise in the topic area.

On the matter of rewards for finding dupes, I upvoted [Reward finding duplicate questions - +10, +2, -5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5) but you should know it's [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: I really wouldn't classify that as a **terrible** approach. **Of course** the ones closing it should review the close-vote independently, if they aren't, they wouldn't be doing it in the review queue either. IMO, it's actually much better approach since it eliminates the question from bothering other active / non-active users if it is worthy of closing.

Comment: Also, I generally stick to questions (in the queue) for the topics that I have some expertise in, because at times there is genuine doubt on whether some question could be on-topic or not depending on the programming language / tool (I've at least seen such differences in voting between Javascript & Python). So, even if it is not necessary, it definitely helps to have expertise in the topic of the question that you are voting to close.

Comment: I certainly agree that using a chat room as a close-voting ring is not a good plan. In the SO Python room we try to avoid encouraging a mob mentality, and we expect people to personally evaluate questions they close-vote. We also discuss borderline questions as to whether they merit closing, and what's the best close reason.

Comment: (cont) We encourage people to post constructive comments on such borderline questions to assist the OP in improving them so that they don't need closing. We also ask people to _not_ ask for close votes in the room until the question's at least 10 minutes old (unless it's an unsalvageable mess, or a dupe that needs hammering), ideally, we like to give the OP at least 10 minutes to respond to those constructive comments.

Comment: BTW, those aren't just unwritten rules, please see [here](https://sopython.com/wiki/cv-pls) for the SO Python chat room's official policy on close vote requests.

Comment: "The queues are there to help the lower-traffic tags - and they need the help!" - They sure do! The new badges can be supplementary or entirely different than those for review queues. Also, for "it's a thing that happened" can be said for "answered a question" too. That definitely doesn't mean we stop encouraging answering a question!

Comment: In support of @PM2Ring the rules for the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room are roughly modeled in the same spirit as the Python room. SOCVR rules can be found in our [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq)

Answer (score 2):

Try to relate this close vote badge with the existing flagging badge (a.k.a Marshall). Pay attention to the description of the badge.

> Raise 500 helpful flags.

Notice the word **helpful**. You won't get the badge for flagging anything you please, you only get it if the flags you raise are deemed worthy. However, there isn't a way to mark a close vote as helpful. They are votes after all, and no one may argue on the helpfulness of a vote.